# How to list uniques entries in a column and in the corresponding times of their repition in next column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a hospital database which looks something like this:

```
id | patient_name | admitDate        | DischargeDate
1  | john         | 3/01/2011 08:50  | 5/01/2011 12:50
2  | lisa         | 3/01/2011 09:50  | 4/01/2011 13:50
3  | ron          | 5/01/2012 10:40  | 10/01/2012 03:50
4  | howard       | 6/02/2013 08:05  | 10/02/2013 08:50
5  | john         | 6/02/2013 12:04  | 7/02/2013 01:50
```

The `admitDate` is same for many entries (time may be different). I want to find out how many patients were admitted on any particular day so if I do this:

```
select distinct left(admitDate,10),
(select count(distinct left(admitDate,10) ) from hospital) 
from hospital
```

I get output as all distinct admit dates in 1st column and same value 5 in all rows of second column. How do I make it so that only corresponding repetition count is found in 2nd column and not the count of entire `admitDate` set.
datatype of admitdate is varchar(50)

I am using left function because I only have to find out uniqueness in dates not in time.

Expected result:

```
admitDate | Count
3/01/2011 | 2
5/01/2012 | 1
6/02/2013 | 2
```

Current result:

```
admitDate | Count
3/01/2011 | 5
5/01/2012 | 5
6/02/2013 | 5
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your table.

Comment: Add sample data and your expected result.

Comment: added sample data and expected result

Comment: sorry guys deleting the question ,since i missed out on a lot of details ,will post it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `admitDate` Column has Time too, you need use `Convert()` function to eliminate the time  to `group by` your data per each day:

```
Select CONVERT(date, admitDate), count(*)
from hospital 
group by CONVERT(date, admitDate);
```

If you use `Varchar` instead of `Date` data type for your admitDate column you can try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(admitDate, charindex(' ', admitDate) - 1) as ADMITDATE , count(*) as COUNTER
from hospital 
group by LEFT(admitDate, charindex(' ', admitDate) - 1) ;
```

or:

```
SELECT convert(date, (convert(datetime2, admitDate,103)) ), count(*)
from hospital 
group by  convert(date, (convert(datetime2, admitDate,103)) )
```

Comment: please go through question once again i have made some changes

Comment: @SakshamJain have you tried this? The first part of this answer is correct.

Comment: nope does not work, the convert function gives an error, conversion failed when converting date and/or time from char string, i tried this earlier, but left it becuase of the error

Comment: Convert() is a MSSQL function. It should work for Date. Are you sure your admitDate has a date datatype?

Comment: it's not working, idk why, my datatype is varchar(50) here is a photo of the error https://ibb.co/jL1h6Bs

Comment: You should write this information in your question.

Comment: added the data, sorry i didn't know that it was necessary

Comment: I added the new query.  You can use the second one.

Comment: that new query was also showing error, INVALID LENGTH PARAMETER PASSED TO left or substring funtion, so i procedded how you told initially but instead of using convert(date,admitDate) i used convert(date, (convert(datetime2, admitDate,103)) ) and it works, thanks a lot for helping me @Rezu

Comment: Ok. Accept the answer to save others's time

Comment: @SakshamJain normally a datetime is stored as a datetime datatype, not a varchar! Thats why people were confused since you didn't mention that.

Comment: @DaleK oh ok i didn't think about that